# Mistake different dimensions for release/debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, release, dimensions

After setting sdk 28, my project have strangers behaviors. One of these is that if running my app in debug or release mode, I have for one drawable shape a stranger behavior in dimensions. For debug mode all is ok, for release mode no, the dimensions of shape are more big.
I doesn't understand why or what could it be (I thought initially proguard and minify, but after disabling doesn't change nothing).
In android sdk 27, all works fine.
This is the shape code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorBluePrimary" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorLightGray2" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

And this the layout file where is used

```
<it.package.CheckableFrameLayoutIndicator
                android:id="@+id/fl_indicator1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fl_indicator_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fl_indicator_size"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

   android:background="@drawable/fl_registration_indicator_oval_shape"
                android:padding="2dp">
```

Here the results (the problem is the oval shapes):

Debug
[image]

Release

[image]

Comment: where are you using this drawable?

Comment: Could you show this shapes?

Comment: added some codes and pictures, thanks

Comment: the problem is that in debug android choose xxhdpi dimens, in release xxxhdpi....now the question is why? :(

Comment: Are you using app bundle or creating split APKs based on density in production?

Comment: I'm using app bundle